# Plotting clusters using PCA features as X an Y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, plotly

I have applied PCA to a dataframe in order to plot clusters based on K-means. Since i have like 24 features in my original df, i don't want to plot clusters based in only 3 or 3 features at each time. So what i want to do, is to plot the combinations of those features, to get a more general/representative graphical respresentation of each feature in the clusters.

I extracted the components using `pca.components_` and i have created the following df of components:

```
                         PC-1       PC-2
media_bi_mov         0.003094   0.050599
media_bi_post        0.000762   0.028931
total_mov_prod_300   0.000836   0.573675
codsprod_0           0.440476  -0.004404
codsprod_1           0.008005   0.105349
codsprod_2           0.002851   0.042459
codsprod_3           0.001078   0.009355
codsprod_4          -0.011922  -0.022020
idaplic_0            0.392229  -0.002817
idaplic_1            0.003001   0.004822
idaplic_2            0.044730  -0.001148
idaplic_3            0.097695  -0.008628
idaplic_4            0.024273   0.486973
idaplic_5            0.234798  -0.033369
idaplic_6            0.019329   0.015455
idempro_36           0.000401  -0.000438
idempro_38           0.032149   0.292137
idempro_49           0.439413  -0.023269
codmonsw_EUR         0.440543  -0.002770
codmonsw_USD         0.000378   0.000664
resto_codsprod       0.011406   0.011731
resto_idaplic        0.041649   0.005692
días_entre_ops      -0.011129  -0.015144
frecuencia           0.440543  -0.002770
valor_total_eur      0.000836   0.573675
```

normally i would plot the clusters using `kmeans.labels_` to apply a different color to each cluster if this was the original df. But my issue now is that i can't use `kmeans.labels_` to differentiate each cluster in this pca-reduced df, since `kmeans.labels_` will have a bigger length.

How can i apply color to differentiate the clusters in this dataframe??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't realise the solution to this problem was so easy: I just needed to run kmeans on the components df to get the cluster labels for each feature in each principal component. Hope this will help someone with the same doubts as me.